# TODO App with Sharing Feature for VIEWING Only, Not Assigning Tasks to Others

Tags: android, iphone-app, sharing, todo

I'm looking for a free todo list app (iPhone and android) that would allow sharing my daily todo lists with a friend. I don't want this friend to be assigned to do anything, so I don't want them to be able to check mark or edit my lists. I only want them to see my list. The same way, I want them to share their lists with me, such that I can only see their list without being able to edit them.

I have tried several apps, including Wunderlist, Remember The Milk, Any.Do, etc. and none seem to have this feature. They all allow sharing your lists, and once the list is shared, the other person can edit that list.

I'd also be very keen on something with not too many features; just a simple app with this feature on top of everything else that it can offer. Any help?

Comment: If my answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer; I had given you an upvote, but Evernote was not what I was looking for, that's why I haven't marked it as accepted and I still welcome new answers that would point at a dedicated todo app rather than something like Evernote.

Comment: That's absolutely fine, I just left the comment in the case you might have forgotten about this question.

Answer (score 3):

[Evernote](http://evernote.com) can be used to share notes (containing any text, including to-dos with checkboxes) both in read/write and read-only mode. For the latter option, you can:

- send a note via email
- create a public link for the note and share the link

You can also create a notebook consisting of several notes and share that as read only.